Talend Data Catalog -Displaying Specific Models to Users in Talend Data Catalog
I need some assistance with Talend Data Catalog. In the Repository under the Manage section, I created a new folder called "DI_JOB," which contains three models: a connection to Excel and Delimited File, an Oracle connection, and a Talend Studio job to transfer data from Excel to Oracle. Additionally, in the Manage -> Repository section, I have multiple folders with various jobs, including a folder called "Configuration" with published access. Whenever I create a new model, it appears alongside other models in the repository. How can I show a user a specific set of models from the repository? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated
TLDR: I want to Modify in Talend Catalog in Such a way  that when the Intended User Logs in, it would see the Enterprise Architecture only of a specific job.
In the Architecture view all the components are seen, out of which i want to show a set of components to a User. how can i achieve that in Talend Data Catalog.
PS: ATTACHED Some Snips for better understanding.
This is My Repository Manager in which i want to show only the Architecture Diagram of the 3 Jobs (Data Integration,Excel,Oracle)
This is my repository View:
enter image description here

This is My Actual Architecture View:
enter image description here
I Want to show Results like this when the assigned user Logs in:
enter image description here
Thanks and Regards,
I tried creating a new folder called "DI_JOB" in the Talend Data Catalog Repository, which contains three models: a connection to Excel and Delimited File, an Oracle connection, and a Talend Studio job to transfer data from Excel to Oracle. Additionally, I set up multiple folders in the Repository section with various jobs and a "Configuration" folder with published access. I expected that by doing this, I could easily display a specific set of models to a user. However, whenever I create a new model, it simply shows up alongside other models in the repository, and I am unable to display only the specific models I want to show to a user.
